# Improve performance - perhaps parallel implementation

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

We have a Visual Studio 2017 extension, which creates a solution in VS, loads files from the database into the created project and then compiles it.

This takes a couple of minutes, and I want to do it faster.
I know there are tools out there, I just don't know what to google for exactly.
So I don't expect someone to re-write my code (although a quick example would be great!) but some guidance as to what I could use would be very helpful.

So here we have the method that creates the solution and takes care of loading the files from the database into it:

```
public void LoadFilesIntoVS()
    {
        CreateSolution();
        LoadCalcFiles();
        LoadTemplateFiles();
        LoadAdvancedCalcFiles();
        LoadOtherFilesIntoSolution();
    }
```

The four Load*XYZ* methods are similar, so I will just continue with an example of LoadCalcFiles().

```
public void LoadCalcFiles()
    {
        CalcFilesList = new ObservableCollection<CalcFile>(BuilderService.GetAllCalcFiles());

        foreach (CalcFile file in CalcFilesList)
        {
            LoadCalcFileIntoSolution(file);
        }
    }
```

LoadCalcFileIntoSolution:

```
private void LoadCalcFileIntoSolution(CalcFile file)
    {
        try
        {
        string sourcePath = BuilderService.GetCalcFileSourcePath(file.ID);
        string fullName = sourcePath.Substring(sourcePath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
        if (!calcObjects.ContainsKey(fullName))
        {              

            if (!File.Exists(sourcePath))
            {
                BuilderService.GenerateCalcFileMethod(file.ID);
            }

            ProjectItem calcFile = LoadAsProjectItem(sourcePath);
            calcObjects.Add(fullName, file);
        }
      }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SetErrorStatus("Problem loading CalcFile into Solution. " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

So yes, I've heard of a parallel foreach. Would it be beneficial to use that in LoadCalcFiles?
Also, could I somehow run the four Load*XYZ* methods at the same time after creating the solution?

Comment: This is likely IO/network bound. Before taking any action, did you profile the execution?

Comment: Ah, you make a good point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest change to `LoadFilesIntoVS()` could be:

```
    Parallel.Invoke(
        () => CreateSolution(),
        () => LoadCalcFiles(),
        () => LoadTemplateFiles(),
        () => LoadAdvancedCalcFiles(),
        () => LoadOtherFilesIntoSolution()
    );
```

this way you keep int synchronous.

But are all files used up front? Else you should consider `Lazy<CalcFile>` in your `CalcFilesList`, so files are first loaded when used first time. It is threadsafe, and you bootstrap time will be close to zero.

Comment: Thank you! I need all the files up front. The order of the LoadXYZ methods (after the solution has been created) is not important. Would that change anything?

Comment: When working with threads, there is no guaranty of execution order. So if anything must be done before something else, you have to call them in sequence. So `Parallel.Invoke` returns when all threads are done, and the threads are executed in "random" order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void LoadFilesIntoVS()
    {
        CreateSolution();
        new Thread(LoadCalcFiles).        Start();
        new Thread(LoadTemplateFiles).    Start();
        new Thread(LoadAdvancedCalcFiles).Start();
        LoadOtherFilesIntoSolution();
    }
```